# pKa of the alpha proton of an alpha amino ester

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, amino-acids

Is there a theoretical pKa value for the proton on the alpha carbon of a methylated amino acid, or just a general alpha amino methyl ester?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will depend on what is attached to the N. In the O'Donnell alkylation procedure where the N is protected as a benzophene imine, the pKa of the glycine proton is estimated at 18.7 and the alanine proton 22.8  source [here](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/o-donnell-amino-acid-synthesis.shtm)